# Combining multiple log lines from Loki in Grafana

Tags: grafana, fastify, grafana-loki, logql

I have stream of http logs (fastify pino format) via Loki that look like:

```
[2022-07-25T16:59:40.796Z] INFO: incoming request {"req":{"method":"GET","url":"/api/v1/teams/6vYE9rpOPl/members","hostname":"forge.flowforge.loc","remoteAddress":"10.1.106.162","remotePort":38422},"reqId":"req-t6"}
[2022-07-25T16:59:40.810Z] INFO: request completed {"res":{"statusCode":200},"responseTime":13.292339086532593,"reqId":"req-t6"}
```

I'd like to display average response time by path, but I'm struggling to work out how to combine the 2 log lines correlated by the `reqId` to get the `url` and `responseTime` together.

I can extract and parse the json for the 2 lines separately but not together.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's doable with Loki alone. For that you would need either:

- some kind of a join, which is not supported (see https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/3567), or
- some kind of a group-by/aggregation which is supported but in a very limited way (https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/metric_queries/#log-range-aggregations)

One solution I can think of is using [Grafana transformations](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/):

- use LogQL [pattern](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#parser-expression) and  [line_format](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#line-format-expression) to extract the JSON part from the logs, so that the `line` field becomes a valid JSON. Do not parse the JSON in LogQL: the extracted fields wouldn't be recognized by the Grafana transformations later on.
- apply "extract fields" transformation in order to parse the JSON (the transformation is currently in an Alpha version)
- add [merge](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/transformation-functions/#merge) transformation
- [outer join](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/transformation-functions/#join-by-field-outer-join) by reqId
- [group by](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/transformation-functions/#join-by-field-outer-join) reqId

Grafana transformations are pretty powerful but a bit non-intuitive too, so the solution would require some experimenting. The [debug transformation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transform-data/debug-transformation/) functionality might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the accepted answer.

In the end I modified the Fastify logging to include the request details in the response log line which made the whole thing a lot easier to deal with:

```
logger: {
  transport: {
    target: 'pino-pretty',
    options: {
      translateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.l'Z'",
      ignore: 'pid,hostname',
      singleLine: true
    }
  },
  level: loggerLevel,
  serializers: {
    res (reply) {
      return {
        statusCode: reply.statusCode,
        request: {
          url: reply.request?.raw?.url,
          method: reply.request?.method,
          remoteAddress: reply.request?.socket.remoteAddress,
          remotePort: reply.request?.socket.remotePort
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```